# What do I not understand about unpack in Lua

Tags: lua

I am working with some lua code (extracted from an English Wiktionary module) and do not understand the problem:

```lua
t = {
      [3] = "continent",
    }

function vprint (val)
  return val or 'nil'
end

prev_qualifier, this_qualifier, bare_placetype = unpack(t)
print('prev_qualifier=' .. vprint(prev_qualifier) .. ', this_qualifier=' .. vprint(this_qualifier) .. ', bare_placetype=' .. vprint(bare_placetype))
```

In Lua5.1, I run the code and get :

```
prev_qualifier=nil, this_qualifier=nil, bare_placetype=nil
```

I would expect `bare_qualifier`to be equal to `'continent'`.

To go further, the code :

```lua
prev_qualifier, this_qualifier, bare_placetype = t[1], t[2], t[3]
print('prev_qualifier=' .. vprint(prev_qualifier) .. ', this_qualifier=' .. vprint(this_qualifier) .. ', bare_placetype=' .. vprint(bare_placetype))
```

Will correctly display:

```
prev_qualifier=nil, this_qualifier=nil, bare_placetype=continent
```

In the documentation, it seems that both assignations should be equivalent.

What do I miss here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `unpack` with sparse arrays, you need to pass two more parameters to it:

```lua
local one, two, three = unpack ({ [3] = 'Three' }, 1, 3 })
```

The second parametre is the first element to uppack, `1` by default; the third is the last item to unpack, `#{ [3] = 'Three' }` by default, which is zero for tables with absent first (`…[1]`) item, so you have to know it.

See [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack)

> `unpack (list [, i [, j]])`
>
> Returns the elements from the given table. This function is equivalent to
> `return list[i], list[i+1], ···, list[j]`
> except that the above code can be written only for a fixed number of elements. By default, `i` is `1` and `j` is the length of the list, as defined by the length operator (see §2.5.5).

Answer (score 0):

The array part of a table has a length defined by the first non-`nil` entry in the array. If `t[1]` is `nil` (and it is), then the length of the array is 0. It doesn't matter if `t[3]` is non-`nil`; that's considered just a key that happens to be an integer.

If you don't give `unpack` a size, it works based on the size of the array part of a table. But you *can* give `unpack` a size (more specifically, a start/end range), so you should do that.

```
prev_qualifier, this_qualifier, bare_placetype = unpack(t, 1, 3)
```